# Данные с датой из firebase в graphview

Tags: java, android, firebase

Есть база данных firebase, где хранятся очки пользователей, которые они зарабатывают каждый день. Я хочу сделать график, который будет отображать общее число всех заработанных очков ЗА ДЕНЬ. Как это можно сделать? Можно ли как-то автоматически, например в 00:00, записывать все заработанные очки за день на стороне firebase?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На стороне firebase это можно сделать используя cloud function, либо через REST API работая с базой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил это задачу с помощью скрипта Cloud Functions, который каждый день вызывается с помощью [Cron job.](https://cron-job.org/en/)